# Cognos Chart add values on it active report

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I created chart to show all data by 24 hours of the day the thing here it only show that in in the 24 hours for example it might show only 13 as there no other intersect in the  database i want to show all 24 hour and it hit the column on 13 if it's only the one having data i tried lot of things but couldn't figure it out yet any hints

Comment: You'll need something along the lines of a time table that has all 24 hours in it.  Then you use an outer join from that table to your data table to get all 24 hours and any matching data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with numbers and select first 24 of them. Alternatively you can outter join your data with this query:

```
select 1 as Number

Union All

Select 2

Union All

Select 3

...

Union All

Select 24
```

You can add this query as a separate SQL Query in Cognos report.